# point news list view pagination to different news list view plugin (Typo3, News system)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the following situation:

Page 1 has 2 news plugins: plugin 1 for a thumbnail view of the first 6 news records, and plugin 2 showing a list view of the rest.

Problem: the pagination of plugin 2 (list view) points to the same page, showing both thumbs and list view.

However, the pagination should point to plugin 3 on another page, showing a list view only (no more thumbnail view on top of the page).

Here a picture:

[image]

I can't figure out how to implement this. I am not sure if this is even possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

My first concern would be: pagination needs a constant number of items. do you have the same number of items on the first page than on the other? if you add pagination the first plugin would use a pagelength of 6, the pagination of the second plugin e.g. of 4 and the third plugin maybe of 10.

The second problem would be: the pagination VH generates links to the same page, you need to generate links by your own: use the other page-id and add a page offset.

Maybe you can use a static link ('more news') on the first page which just links to the second page of the complete list on the other page.
This also avoids having special handling for links to the first news on the first page.

Comment: Static link ('more news') is a good idea. I need to place 2 plugins on the first page: plugin 1 (thumbnail view, no pagination) records 1-6, plugin 2 (list view, no pagination but the static link to page 2) records e.g. 7-15. Then on the second page plugin 3 (list view again) records 16-end. This should work, right?